# Modify UNet to take an arbitrary input dimension?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, unet-neural-network

I have a network that's pretty much UNet. However, the model crashed when I feed in input size of 3x1x1 (channel =3, height =1, width=1) since the first max pooling (with kernel size =2 and stride =2) will reduce the dimension into 3x0x0.

How do I modify Unet model such that it can take my 3x1x1 input and handle arbitrary number of poolings? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the meaning of a UNet applied to a single pixel? This makes no sense. What are you truly trying to achieve here?

Comment: It's an assignment to make a FCN model. So I'm using Unet as my base model and this model also has to be able to handle any input size. I understand it doesn't make sense to have this input. Or another example if  the input size is ( 3, 2, 16), the model will crash on the 2nd pooling since it's running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

One must normalize sizes of images with preprocessing, see `torchvision.transforms.functional.resize`.